# По поводу загрузки изображения во vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите, как можно загрузить изображение во vue.js без перезагрузки страницы, то есть только добавляю, и отображает на странице мгновенно

```
  <input type="file" v-model="imgs">
  <img v-bind:src="imgs">
```

Пробовал так, не катит.

Comment: Без загрузки на сервер?

Comment: Да. Загрузку на сервер уже сделал

Comment: У вас загрузка на сервер есть, значит есть разные способы, предположим вы используете метод `fetch`. Из самого метода верните просто ссылку на уже загруженную картинку и выведите её.

Comment: А другого способа нет? То backend у меня на laravel, запутано получится

Comment: А это не оно? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803012/v-model-doesnt-support-input-type-file

Comment: Спасибо, нашел, в этой теме :)
https://codepen.io/Atinux/pen/qOvawK/

Comment: Ну я как бы это и имел в виду))